# Заменить кнопку Cancel на кнопку Отмена в wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Занимаюсь переводом на русский язык интерфейса одной opensource программы. Написана на python, графический интерфейс на WxPython. В диалоговых окнах используются стандартные кнопки ОК и Cancel: `(topsizer.Add(self.CreateSeparatedButtonSizer(wx.OK+wx.CANCEL), 0, wx.EXPAND)).`

Каким образом можно заменить кнопку Cancel на Отмена? С wxpython раньше не работал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст на кнопках, определяемых константами, зависит от текущей локали. Для en_US будет отображаться "Cancel", а для ru_RU будет "Отмена".

Comment: Все, что можно было перевести с помощи локали я перевел. В директории locale лежали еще немецкая, французкая и испанские локали. Я их использовал как шаблон для создания русской локали. Кнопки ОК и Cancel в них, кстати, тоже остались на английском. Так как эти кнопки взяты из wx-библиотеки